# Cancel appointment gives internal server error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to cancel an appointment in Microsoft bookings, when I request for cancellation through api it gives internal server error

[image]

is this because of server down or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried at my end (with delegated permissions & M365 mailbox) and it's working for me. Just to isolate the issue further, check if you're trying with Application permissions/personal mailbox then it won't work for you - as its not supported at this point.

Comment: i'm trying with delegated permission only

Comment: still not working with cancel

Comment: Delete works though

Comment: what is difference b/w cancel and delete an appoinment?

Comment: With Cancel the specified bookingAppointment in the specified bookingbusiness, and send a message to the involved customer and staff members, wherein Delete will delete a bookingAppointment in the specified bookingbusiness and no message will be sent.

Comment: Its worth to check the API call and see if you're passing all the parameters and you're targeting only M365 mailboxes (not personal accounts).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232717/discussion-between-dev-and-chinnarajs).